# Container of variadic template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a wrapper for `std::function`s with return type `void` and a variable number of `std::string` arguments.

```
template<class... Args>
class ConsoleCommand
{
    public:
        ConsoleCommand(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(Args...)>& function) :
            name{ name },
            function{ function }
        {

        }

        void operator()(Args... args)
        {
            function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::function<void(Args...)> function;
};
```

So this works right, except for the fact that the arity of the function has to be ingrained into the type of the instance, and I'm trying to avoid that.

```
ConsoleCommand<std::string> ex1; //unary function
ConsoleCommand<std::string, std::string> ex2; //dyadic function
```

I want to have a container of these objects,  (`std::vector<ConsoleCommand<std::string>>`) and it would be really neat if I could make the class template argument only refer to the type of the arguments, not the whole pack.

```
template<class Args>
class ConsoleCommand
{
    public:
        ConsoleCommand(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(Args...)>& function) :
            name{ name },
            function{ function }
        {

        }

        void operator()(Args... args)
        {
            function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::function<void(Args...)> function;
};
```

I tried this but it didn't work. Would there be any workaround for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you want to use that wrapper? This question seems incomplete

Comment: You might have alias to have `ConsoleCommandN<string, 4>` equivalent to `ConsoleCommand<string, string, string, string>`.

Comment: This is impossible with the way you're using `std::function`. `std::function` can't not know how many parameters it's going to take. You probably want to use a type-erasure type like `any` or a variable-size view type like `span` for `std::function`'s argument type instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using type erasure, it's a common way of hiding away a template under runtime type information / polymorphism.

Basically you have a virtual base class with no / little functionality and a derived class which implements storage / access.

Then you can use virtual methods or dynamic_cast to access the templated derived class.

Here is an example to match your question:

```
class ConsoleCommand
{
private:
    // Dummy virtual base class, used to hide the template behind RTTI
    struct FunctionWrapperBase
    {
        // Needs to be virtual to enable RTTI
        virtual ~FunctionWrapperBase() {}
    };

    // Concrete type
    template<class... Args>
    struct FunctionWrapperConcrete : FunctionWrapperBase
    {
        // Just holds the function
        FunctionWrapperConcrete(std::function<void(Args...)> function)
        : function(function) {}

        std::function<void(Args...)> function;
    };

    std::string name;
    // (smart) Pointer to the virtual wrapper class
    std::unique_ptr<FunctionWrapperBase> erased_wrapper;

    // This calls the function, outside operator() so we ensure Args are all strings
    template<class... Args>
    void call_all_strings(Args... args)
    {
        auto concrete = dynamic_cast<FunctionWrapperConcrete<std::decay_t<Args>...>*>(erased_wrapper.get());
        if ( concrete )
            concrete->function(args...);
    }

public:
    template<class... Args>
    ConsoleCommand(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(Args...)>& function) :
        name{ name },
        erased_wrapper{ std::make_unique<FunctionWrapperConcrete<Args...>>(function) }
    {

    }

    template<class... Args>
    void operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        call_all_strings(std::string(args)...);
    }
};
```

You could even extend it so you can store any callable (not just std::function) as this is similar to how std::function is implemented